# How to bold the text which is inside ** in TextView like WhatsApp

Tags: android

I want to bold the text which is inside ** . I am taking the text as input through EditText and than putting it in Text View similar to Whatsapp[image: ex. hello *world*]

Comment: Using **`SpannableString`**

Comment: You could use `Html.fromHtml()` method to make text bold when displayed in `TextView`.
To make part of a text bold, you can do it like this, 

    `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Sample text with <b>bold</b> style"))`

The text to make bold, you cant get by searching for `*` in the input text.  
`Html.fromHtml()` method returns `SpannableString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("Text here with * inside *");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), INT_START, INT_END, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TextView tv=new TextView(context);
tv.setText(str);
```

where INT_START and INT_END will be the position of the `*`

Comment: if there are multiple bold text then ??